# how to fast self join (same as distinct on)?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a table like following:

```
student_score
  id          int
  student_id  int
  score       int
  type        int
  is_repeat   boolean
  created_at  int
```

Suppose I want to get latest exam score of students with type < 10 and is_repeat equals false, so I have a view like:

```
CREATE VIEW view_latest_student_score
AS
SELECT
  s1.*
FROM student_score s1
LEFT JOIN student_score s2
  ON s1.student_id = s2.student_id
  AND s2.type < 10
  AND s2.is_repeat = FALSE
  AND s1.id < s2.id
WHERE s1.type < 10
  AND s1.is_repeat = FALSE
  AND s2.id IS NULL;
```

So how to create index for this kind of view? Currently, I have index on `student_id` (`id` is pk). Is there some best practice for this kind of self join?

Sometimes I will query like this view with column score or type. So should I add index like (student_id, score) or (score, student_id)?

Comment: In where clause s2.id Is null but in on clause s2.id > s1.id  how it will work ?

Comment: @Gaj it is left join not inner join. It means that in the group with same student_id `cannot` find an s2.id that large than s1.id which means s1.id is the largest one in this group.

Comment: hope id is PK in this case how it will be null?

Comment: @Gaj This is a common anti-join setup. You LEFT JOIN a table, and then require a non-nullable column in that table to be null. That forces the query to only return results from the first table (the FROM table) where there are no matching results in the second (the LEFT JOINed table).

Comment: In this case why unnecessary join there? Generally left join will be costly also I couldn’t see any conditions related to latest exam score. Hope student score table have records for who are all attend exam only.

Answer (score 0):

Create a multicolumn index on `is_repeat + type` (the order of columns matters).
It may be used to satisfy this condition against `s` table to filter out some rows using index range scan:

```
WHERE s1.type < 10
  AND s1.is_repeat = FALSE
```

(**may by used - but not must be used** - it depends on selectivity of the query, the database may prefer a full table scan instead of using this index when the WHERE condition selects more than 5~10% rows of the table):

---

Create also second index on `student_id` column` for this JOIN condition:

```
 ON s1.student_id = s2.student_id
  AND s2.type < 10
  AND s2.is_repeat = FALSE
  AND s1.id < s2.id
```

You may also consider creating a multicolumn index on: `student_id + is_repeat + type` (in this particular order of columns) for this case, but my guess is that the index on `student_id` will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only dealing with rows where type < 10 and is_repeat = FALSE, a partial index should suffice. (In a partial index, a WHERE condition can limit the index rows to those where type < 10 and is_repeat = FALSE, so the optimizer doesn't need to seek those rows out).

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test ON student_score 
    (student_id, score, type, is_repeat, created_at) 
WHERE TYPE < 10 AND is_repeat = FALSE
```